# Call two different function based on some value using delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have two function with different functionality and i want to call them based on some value. without if else or switch case block. like i have

```
Dictionary<string, string> intentMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
intentMap.Add("rootIntent", "TicketbookingInformation");
intentMap.Add("rootIntent", "OrderInformation");

and i have two function 

public bool BookTicket()
{
  // to do
}

public bool BookOrder()
{
  // to do
}
```

I want to switch these function if `intentMap` has `TicketbookingInformation`  then call `BookTicket` method or if `intentMap` has `OrderInformation` then call `BookOrder` method.

I want to do in generic way using deleagtes so in future if I have some more use case (new method), so i can utilize the same functionlaity without modifying much.

Comment: With the knowledge that this probably isn't production code, I still feel the need to point out that adding two values with the same key to a `Dictionary` like you are doing is going to throw an `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

Use another dictionary, this time of type `<string, Func<bool>`:

```
var delegateMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<bool>>()
{
    { "TicketBookingInformation", BookTicket },
    { "OrderInformation", BookOrder }
};

foreach (var intent in intentMap)
{
    bool result = delegateMap[intent.Value]();
}
```

Comment: There was few issues with the `foreach` i have corrected them, please take a look

Comment: @un-lucky They were not issues. I was looping over the `intentMap` that OP introduced in the question and invoking the `Func` in the delegate dictionary that corresponds with the value of the `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Actually the Op's input was wrong, it contains same key for two different items, which is not allowed. So your answer is enough to get what he expected

Comment: @un-lucky I realize, and I commented on it too. I also pointed out that the code in his question was (hopefully) not production code.

Comment: @un-lucky And even if that code is an exception waiting to happen, it gets the point across of what he is trying to do, so I used it as part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer to your question directly. @Abion47 has answered perfectly fine, i would answer the same.

But i think having having two dictionaries one having the token, and another having the delegate is more obscure then having single method for dispatching the result.

Here is my point with a bit code.

This the dictionary version.

```
var intentMap = new Dicionary<string, string>();

var delegateMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<bool>>();
delegate.Map.Add("TicketbookingInformation", BookTicket);
delegateMap.Add("OrderInformation", BookOrder);
```

Then the usage will be something like this

```
var token = ...;
if(intentMap.ContainsKey(token))
{
    var delegateToken = intenMap[token];
    if(delegateMap.ContainsKey(delegateToken))
    {
       var delegatedMethod = delegateMap(delegateToken);

        return delegatedMethod();
    }
}
```

So adding new token and delegate will means extending the dictionaries and i can't see how this is different then extending a switch statement.

Second version which i think will be generic enough and will need not too much modification where used will be something like this.

First i will suggest having the `"TicketbookingInformation"` and `"OrderInformation"` as enumeration type, this way having a switch statement will benefit from the compiler helping when you have some missing case to handle. This of course is applicable if you know upfront all the possible values ;]

```
bool PredicateDispatch(DelegateToken token)
{
      switch(token)
      {
          DelegateToken.TicketbookingInformation: return BookTicket();
          DelegateToken.OrderInformation: return BookOrder()
      }

}
```

this way you will need to extend this single method to handle new tokens. It is more readable approach and you don't lose anything compared with the dictionary version. So i will do it this way. If don't have of course more complicated code and your example is more more simplified ;]